# What is faster - fetching a column from n columns with a single value of size t, or fetching it from it from 1 column but of the size n*t?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a "NAMES" table that has a single `Name` column of type `varchar(10)`; this table has 500 rows.  I also have a "NAME_COLLECTIONS" table with one column of type `longtext`; in the table's single row, that column contains a string of the length 5500.

Will `SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE :Name = 'Tom';` run slower than  `SELECT * FROM NAME_COLLECTIONS;`?

How will increasing the number of columns in NAMES vs increasing the size of the single text in NAME_COLLECTIONS affect performance?

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that all else being equal, splitting the data over more rows would create a bit more overhead for the DBMS in a full table scan, but rarely is all else equal.  This is anyway a largely vacuous question -- it is hard to imagine a useful application in which both proposed representations of the data are equally appropriate *semantically*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE Name = 'Tom';
```

This should be quicker, assuming you have an index on the column (which you should, since you seem to be trying to get optimal performance). It only has to read a single row from the index, and the row will occupy a single page of data.

Whereas a `longtext` may span multiple pages of data, and every read of your list of names will be forced to read the whole collection.

I recommend you model your data properly, with one row per name, if you want to search for a specific name. And create an index for that column.

Although 500 rows is insignificant to MySQL. It'll probably fit on a few pages in the buffer pool in memory regardless, so you shouldn't be preoccupied with performance until you get a larger dataset.

By the way, your syntax `WHERE :Name = 'Tom'` isn't right. The colon-prefixed column name appears to be a named parameter placeholder, not a column name. A parameter placeholder can only be a fixed string, not the name of a column.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write Name = :Name; It's late and I'm tired. Anyway thanks for the answer!